# Shopify app that embeds liquid template somewhere into item page?

Tags: shopify

I want to have an app that embeds a little html/liquid template into each Item page in the store. What kind of app would do this or which of the APIs would I use.

It seems like I want an app proxy, but as far as I understand, an app proxy can only be on its own page, not embedded into another page on the store.

Answer (score 0):

An App Proxy is actually the perfect mechanism for you. It allows you to setup a secure Ajax call to your App, and your App returns HTML (or JSON or whatever you want).

So you setup a Proxy, and then anywhere in your Shopify templates, be it theme.liquid, or index.liquid, or product.liquid, you make an Ajax call to get content to render. And you render it. And it is a thing of beauty. And yes, it appears the the App Proxy is only for a one page wonderkin of Liquid, but that is so not true at all. It is for as many supporting purposes as you can dream up.